# PHP MVC - URL without action

Tags: php, model-view-controller, url, frameworks, action

I'm currently creating my own custom MVC framework in PHP that uses the MVC URL standard:
**example.com/{controller}/{action}/{id}**

This works fine, however, one of my controllers called "books" does not need the action in the URL:
**example.com/{controller}/{id}**

The index method of the books controller displays a list of books:
**example.com/books**

I want the controller to display a specific book if an ID follows:
**example.com/books/47**

At the moment, I have to use this URL to view a specific book which isn't as nice:
**example.com/books/view/47**

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide the ability to create custom URLs, then you will have to look into creating a routing mechanism. Usually in PHP it is done by employing simplified URL patterns, that are transformed into regular expression.

Then, when user's request gets handled at bootstrap stage, the routing mechanism applies all of the regular expressions on by one. When the match is found, the appropriate route is selected.

The the resulting state of request instance is combination of the data that was extracted with regular expressions, supplemented by default values that are associated with each of those patterns.